# Убрать повторяющуюся часть заголовков в Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Подскажите как убрать "nan|" из названий заголовков в Dataframe Pandas без переименования каждого отдельного столбца?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: использовал это решение, подошло

df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('nan|',''))

Comment: Покажите, как создается ваш датафрейм с такими дивными заголовкам. Может проще это будет  сделать на этом этапе.

Comment: пример данных должен быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скришотом

Answer (score 2):

для вашего конкретного случая можно сделать проще. предположим, есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"nan|one":[1,2,3],"nan|two":[11,22,33],"nan|three":[111,222,333]})
```

```
   nan|one  nan|two  nan|three
0        1       11        111
1        2       22        222
2        3       33        333
```

делаем простое преобразование:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("|").str[1]
```

теперь df:

```
   one  two  three
0    1   11    111
1    2   22    222
2    3   33    333
```

И я бы советовал обратить внимание на комментарий пользователя @passant - возможно, проще было бы избавиться от таких имен на этапе формирования датафрейма.

**UPDATE**

в боле общем случае можно обойтись лямбдой и replace

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('nan|',''))
```

Comment: Можно ли ограничить действие на первые 10 колонок? 
Справа от выведенных мной на скрине есть те, которые соединились нормально без nan, и действие данной функции сейчас распространяется и на них

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

есть еще вариант:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nan|col1': [1,2,3],'nan|col2':[4,5,6],'nan|col3':[7,8,9]})
'''
   nan|col1  nan|col2  nan|col3
0         1         4         7
1         2         5         8
2         3         6         9
'''

df = df.rename(lambda x: x[4:],axis=1)
'''
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: df1]

переносим названия столбцов в список

```
listt = dff.columns.tolist()
```

меняем в списке части названия на заданные

```
listt = [i.replace('a', 'd') for i in listt]
```

устанавливаем новый список в качестве заголовков

```
dff.columns = listt

dff
```

[image: df2]